# MySQL Master-Slave Replication When Master is Down

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, replication, haproxy

I'm running MySQL as the database on Ubuntu instances. I'm using MySQL Master-Slave replication where master's changes will be written to slave and slave's changes will not be reflected on the master. That's fine. I'm using a HAProxy load balancer to front the MySQL instances where all the requests will be sent to master MySQL instance. If the master MySQL instance is down slave MySQL instance will act as master and HAProxy will send all the requests to salve. Active-Passive scenario.

```
HAProxy - 192.168.A.ABC
MySQL Master - 192.168.A.ABD
MySQL Slave - 192.168.A.ABE
```

Let's assume that the MySQL master(192.168.A.ABD) is down. Now all the requests will be sent to MySQL slave(192.168.A.ABE) by HAProxy where now he acts as the master MySQL server for the time being.

My problems are

- What happens when original master MySQL instance(192.168.A.ABD) is up?
- Will changes written to new MySQL master (192.168.A.ABE) be replicated to original master(192.168.A.ABD) again?

How should I address this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I should say that I have never used HA Proxy so con't comment on that directly.

However, in your current setup the Master (ABD) will be out of sync, and wont catch up. You will have to rebuild that using mysqlDump or similar tool.

What you would need is a `Master < > Master` setup (as opposed to `Master > Slave`), which enables you to write to either database and have it reflected in the other. This isn't quite as straight forward as it sounds though.

Assuming you already have your `master > slave` setup, and they are in sync

On the Master (ABD) you want to add:

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1
log-slave-updates
```

On the Slave (ABE) add:

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2
log-slave-updates
```

to your my.cnf files. Restart the Database. This will help to prevent `Duplicate Key Errors`. (n.b. that `log-slave-updates` isn't strictly required but makes it easier to add another slave in future)

Next you want to tell the Master (ABD) to replicate from the Slave (ABE).

Depending on what version of MySQL and if you are using GTID etc. the exact process differs slightly. But basically you are going to issue a `CHANGE MASTER` statement on the Master so it replicates from the slave.

And away you go. You probably want to avoid writing to both at the same time as that opens up a whole other kettle of fish. But if the Master goes down, you can switch your writes to the slave, and when the master comes back up, it will simply start replicating the missing data.

Answer (score -1):

I am considering you scenario

```
Master - 192.168.A.ABD
Slave - 192.168.A.ABE
```

You cannot directly  add the master in system. To Add master in system you need to perform below steps:
1) When master is up you can add this as a slave. So now this happens

```
Master - 192.168.A.ABE
Slave - 192.168.A.ABD
```

2) Then Now U can put master Down. Means You can put `192.168.A.ABD` Down
3) Then Again Add this as slave. So After this You will get below scenarion

```
Master - 192.168.A.ABD
Slave - 192.168.A.ABE
```

You can refer this link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-switch.html